# Change ncurses "cell" size

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses, fixed-width

I'm curently making a pacman game with ncurses but the size of some unicode character are a bit larger than the others (you can see in the image that the ghost is larger than the wall).
[PacMan in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Gyh.png)

To fix that i was thinking of changing the lenght of a char cell in the terminal but i don't know if it's possible and for now i don't really see another way to fix that (i didn't found any other unicode character that look like a ghost).

Comment: This is really not C nor ncurses problem. They both did their job (by sending the terminal the correct code to say "draw a fantom here"). The rest is about the configuration of the virtual terminal program. It is not even coding. Just to about how to configure a given software (a software that happens to be used mainly by people geek enough to use command line. But still, a software like Excel or Word). And [so] is not really the correct place to find power user that know parameters of software. Especially unnamed ones, since that is specific to each terminal program, and you didn't say which.

Comment: Since I've seen this same behavior (large characters being drawn over the next one) before, with many terminals, I would say that this is probably very common tho. Unicode characters come with different sizes. And terminals (usually) use fixed width (for example so that you can do things like what you are doing; obviously, you couldn't do any form of ascii art if they weren't). So they have to deal with this contradiction. And most of them do it by assuming each character has the size of a fixed width "standard ascii" character.

Comment: In other words, you should probably, either stick on simpler, more boring, chars (like `^`) for your ghost. Or use fancy chars, but assume that they may overlap on the next one, So, make it a two space wide fantom, with a overlapped space next to it. And make your corridors 2 chars wide. Because the alternative is to find a terminal that draws ghost as you wish (or find a font configuration that does in your terminal). But that wouldn't be very good practice neither to code a program that runs on terminal, but need user to use the exact same as yours.

Comment: But, well, short answer, (afaik at least) there is no "cell size" in ncurses.

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation @chrslg ! i think i will just use two space for every cell

Comment: Although curses mostly comes from a monospaced model, there *is* a limited concept of variable widths -- a single character can be either 1 (the usual case), 2, or 0 cells wide. (Zero width is used with "combining characters", AKA accent marks.) Check out the (wide-character, not specifically curses) POSIX functions `wcwidth()` and `wcswidth()`. Locale-dependent.